# Compactly embedded in $L^p(0,1)$ but is not a subspace of $C^0[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

By the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem, one knows that the embedding $H^1(0,1) \subset L^2(0,1)$ is compact.

On another hand, by Sobolev inequalities, one also has $H^1(0,1) \subset C^0[0,1]$ (in fact, even $C^{0,\frac{1}{2}}$ in this one-dimensional case, by using the fundamental theorem of calculus and some Cauchy-Schwartz arguments).

My question is whether there exists some "intermediate subspace" in the following sense.

> Namely, does there exists a Hilbert space $H$ which is compactly embedded in $L^p(0,1)$ for some $p\geq 1$, and which is not a subspace of $C^0[0,1]$?

Comment: Choose your favourite function $f \in L^2(0,1) \setminus C^0[0,1]$, and let $H$ be the span of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such Hilbert spaces exist and they are a special case of **fractional Sobolev spaces**.
For $\alpha\in(0,1/2)$ we have
$H^\alpha(0,1)\subset L^2(0,1)$ by definition,
and one can show that the step function which is $1$ on $(1/2,1)$ and $0$ else
is in $H^\alpha(0,1)$.
Since this function is not continuous,
$H^\alpha(0,1)$ does not embed in $C^0[0,1]$.

See also [Proof that the characteristic function of a bounded open set is in $H^{\alpha}$ iff $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825303/proof-that-the-characteristic-function-of-a-bounded-open-set-is-in-h-alpha?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and [To what fractional Sobolev spaces does the step function belong? (Sobolev-Slobodeckij norm of step function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382382/to-what-fractional-sobolev-spaces-does-the-step-function-belong-sobolev-slobod)
for more details.

It is also known that $H^\alpha(0,1)$ embeds compactly into
$L^2(0,1)$ for $\alpha\in (0,1/2)$.
This follows from Theorem 7.1 [in this pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Just to make things clear, are you saying that fractional Sobolev of order $\alpha < \frac12$ compactly embeds into $L^2(0,1)$?

Comment: @bgsk good point, I skipped over that. But yes, the embedding is compact, and I added a source.